# Is there a shortcut to clear PowerShell screen and scrollback?

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

### Question

Anybody knows if there is a shortcut to clear PowerShell screen and scrollback (equivalent of `cls` command) ?

### More details with an example

Let say I have this:
[image: Initial state]

I know there is a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut but that leaves scrollback, here is state after using it:
[image: State after Ctrl + L]

What I want is a shortcut which makes me in a state like after use of `cls` command where screen is clear and there is no more scrollback:
[image: About to run cls command]

[image: State after cls]

Comment: Have you tried CLS  ?  Works for me.

Comment: @John I would assume that they want an actual Ctrl-key keyboard shortcut that can be done quickly and potentially in just two keys without having to type `cls<enter>`. They appear to know about `cls` already.

Comment: _(For what it's worth, ***cls*** is an alias for ***Clear-Host***)_

Comment: CLS is as fast as any shortcut for me

Comment: @John `cls` only works when the command interpreter is active.

Comment: Well, yes.  That is when I would use it.

Comment: I didn't find a shortcut for Clear-Host/cls/clear. A solution might to use AutoHotKey to assign a shortcut for this command, however it couldn't be used when another command is active.

Comment: @John, indeed as other answered I already know `cls` and want a keyboard shortcut, even if as you mentioned `cls` is quite fast, and @harrymc, thanks I did not think about it, I have AutoHotKey then I'll look at it, even if I would prefer a specific PowerShell shortcut.

Comment: I have added an answer using AutoHotKey, if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the PSReadLine Module (typically installed with PowerShell). Using keyboard combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>, will run `cls` to clear the screen and scrollback buffer.

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+l -ScriptBlock {
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::RevertLine()
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert('cls')
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```

Comment: Great, added it in my `C:\Users\<myuser>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` and works like a charm !

Comment: Also works if you change `Ctrl+l` to `Alt+k` to mimic clearing the terminal on Mac

Answer (score 1):

The "Clear buffer" command does this. By default that command has no key binding, so you'd have to type <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd> to pull up the command palette and select it. However, you can customize the key bindings. Open the settings window with <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd>, go to the Actions pane, add an action with the command "clear buffer", and pick whatever hotkey you'd like (I suggest <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd>).

Comment: This answer is for Windows Terminal, not pure PowerShell.

Comment: @harrymc "Pure powershell" is not a GUI application. You can run PowerShell on Windows Terminal or on the "classic" Win7-era console. There is zero reason to do the latter.

Comment: I do the zero reason all the time ...

Comment: One of the first things in my profile is to make an alias for Clear-Host: `New-Alias 'c' Clear-Host -Force`.  @Sneftel - Server Core, pwsh (if on non-Windows OS), remoting, not every enterprise env allows you to install Windows Store apps, most enterprises aren't running Win11 yet - those are just a handful of examples among many others.  The "classic Win7-era console" (console host, or conhost.exe) was updated in Windows 10 FYI.  I bind CTRL+SHIFT+X to Clear Buffer in Windows Terminal so I can do it with one hand, and @jfrmilner's solution works in the console just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>F12</kbd>
to the string "Clear-Host":

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe powershell.exe
F12::Sendinput, Clear-Host{Enter}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: While it is a good alternative I prefer jfrmilner's answer, still, upvoted yours too.